# how to copy a class inside of a state?

Tags: scala, copy, lagom

Its quite simple if all of the val in the State is basic data type. if we want to copy a specific value inside of it, it would just be

`copy(specificValue = newValue)`

but how if this specific value, is inside of a class? this is what I have tried but with no avail

`copy(specificClass.specificValue = newValue)`

should I instead create/copy this class outside, then make it like bellow?

`copy(specificClass = newClass)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have

```scala
case class Address(street: String, city: String)
case class User(address: Address, name: String)

val u = User(...)

//to change the city to something else you would do

val another = u.copy(address = u.address.copy(city = "New York")
```

This is cumbersome. I recommend using `quicklens` library which will allow you to write:

```scala
 import com.softwaremill.quicklens._

 val another = u.modify(_.address.city).setTo("New York")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a project named [quicklens](https://github.com/softwaremill/quicklens)

```
import com.softwaremill.quicklens._

case class Street(name: String)
case class Address(street: Street)
case class Person(address: Address, age: Int)

val person = Person(Address(Street("1 Functional Rd.")), 35)

val p2 = person.modify(_.address.street.name).using(_.toUpperCase)
val p3 = person.modify(_.address.street.name).setTo("3 OO Ln.")

// or

val p4 = modify(person)(_.address.street.name).using(_.toUpperCase)
val p5 = modify(person)(_.address.street.name).setTo("3 OO Ln.")
```